# How to mock Membership class in ASP.NET MVC to enable testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-membership

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3 site that allows users to register. To that end I'm using the built in (static) `Membership` class; some say it is bloated but it works well and easily enough so there your are.

Anyway, I've started writing and AdminService class which will handle user account related functionality, and let's assume for the question that it has only one method:

```
public class AdminService : IAdminService
{
   public void DeleteUser(string username)
   {
      Membership.DeleteUser(username);
   }
}
```

Using the Membership class like this wrong in 2 ways: it cannot be injected via IoC and I'm finding it increasingly hard to write specs (test) for `IAdminService` because I cannot mock the Membership class.

Is there a way to make the ASP.NET Membership class test-friendly and Dependency injection friendly without rolling my own?

When it comes to functionality, the Membership class works well and, more importantly, it 
works *now*, so I'm really reluctant to start writing my own MembershipProvider as it would only slow me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create non-empty ASP.NET MVC 3 project there will be AccountModels.cs file in your Models folder. It contains a sample how to deal with membership to enable unit-testing:

```
public interface IMembershipService
{
    int MinPasswordLength { get; }

    bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password);
    MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email);
    bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
}
```

Comment: Thanks UserControl; I normally start with a self-made "template" and I had completely forgotten about the IMembershipService interface.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same situation when I was building out an MVC site, and ended up rolling my own (testable) provider.

That being said, one option would be to just lift the sample implementation from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx) - you could (in theory) just build a FakeProvider, and hard-code the various return methods vs. hit a SQL database.

The total number of methods in one of these is pretty light, and would not be a bad thing to have around for when you want to fake these out.